# How to reduce the number of values on x-axis in a matplotlib graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a graph using matplotlib library.

This is my code:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame()
    df = milo_data2.loc[milo_data2['id'] == device]
    plt.figure()
    plt.title(device)
    plt.ylabel('Counter')   
    plt.plot(df['timestamp'],df['counter'])
```

The graph looks like 
[image]

The values on the x-axis are crowded and not readable.(The bold black line is the group of values overlapping each other) How do I reduce the number of values on the x-axis so that I can see some values on x-axis to get an estimate.

Comment: Make sure time stamp is converted to a number or a datetime before plotting.

Comment: Please post a [minimal, reproducible, working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex). I.e. with dummy data, but that can be run directly on any system.

Comment: pandas is terrible at plotting dates.  I would try `ax.plot_date(x= , y=, data=df)`.  Then you can use the matplotlib date formatters.

Answer (score 2):

You can manually set the ticks to display. For instance, you can leave every tenth tick:

```
ticks = list(df['timestamp'])
plt.xticks([ticks[i] for i in range(len(ticks)) if i % 10 == 0], rotation='vertical')
```

For more information see [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html)